If you delete fewer than $n-1$ edges in $K_n$ then it remains connected.
Consider the complete graph on $n$ vertices, $K_n$.  Show that if you remove any $n-2$ edges, the resulting graph $G$ must be connected.
Attempt
Let $u,v$ be any two vertices in $G$, and we construct a path from $u$ to $v$.  Since not every edge adjacent to $u$ was removed, we may pick the vertex adjacent to it of maximum degree, $u_2$.  $u_2$ must have degree at least 2, since there is at most one vertex of degree 1, and that was either $u$ and so not $u_2$, or we picked $u_2$ to not have degree 1.
Already this seems messy and confusing, and headed in a bad direction.
I thought about looking at connected components, but then this seemed to involve proving certain inequalities of binomials that I'm not able to justify, and are probably beyond the scope of what I'm currently studying.

Like you have observed, by deleting $n-2$ edges we do not create isolated vertices. The idea is to show that if components have larger size, we need to delete even more edges.
Suppose we have a minimum edge cut of $K_n$, giving two components $A, B$ (a minimum edge cut always yields exactly two components). How many edges did we delete to disconnect $A$ from $B$? Well exactly $|A|(n-|A|) = -|A|^2+|A|n$ since all edges between $A$ and $B$ are present in $K_n$. This is a quadratic in $|A|$ with $-1$ leading coefficient, so the smallest value of this quadratic is taken on the boundary of our feasible range of values for $|A|$, i.e., at $|A|=1$ or $|A|=n-1$. Now
$$1(n-1) = n-1 = (n-1)(n-(n-1)),$$
so in both cases, we get the value $n-1$. We conclude that we indeed need to delete at least $n-1$ edges to disconnect $K_n$.

Assume that more than one connected component exists in the resulting graph. Choose one of the components arbitrarily and let $x$ be the number of vertices in this component. To make this component disconnected from the rest of the graph, we need to remove at least $x(n - x)$ edges since there are $n-x$ nodes outside this component. Now we show that $x(n - x) \geq n - 1$ so we need to at least remove $n - 1$ edges.
By rearranging the above inequality we have:
$$
(x-1)n \geq x^2 - 1
$$
By deciding the two sides by $x - 1$ we have $n \geq x + 1$, which is always true since we assumed $x < n$.
So, we need at least $n - 1$ edges to make the graph disconnected.

Label the vertices $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$.  There are $n-1$ mutually disjoint paths connecting $v_1$ to $v_n$ given by $v_1v_n$ and $v_1v_iv_n$ for $2\leq i \leq n-1$.
If you remove fewer than $n-1$ edges, at least one of these paths will remain unaffected, so $v_1$ and $v_n$ will remain connected.
Since the labeling was arbitrary, any two vertices will remain connected, so the graph will be connected.

We say that a graph is $k$-edge-connected if it remains connected if fewer than $k$ edges are removed.
For such graphs, there is a nice equivalent characterization:
A graph $G$ is $k$-connected if and only if every two vertices of G form the endpoints of k paths, no two of which share an edge with each other.
In other words, for every two vertices $v,w\in K_n$, we need to find $k-1$ edge-disjoint paths between them.
Finding these paths shouldn't pose a problem.
